# Make elements "known" to functions in JavaScript before assignment

Tags: javascript, element

I am writing a page using JavaScript, and I have 4 divs, all of which are from the same class. Each div has a function that changes the styles of the other divs (border colour and background colour, for example). The problem is that the last div does not get affected by the functions of the divs above it, because it was not "assigned" yet. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: add your script right before the end of the body or use it at the onload event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {

};
```

Make sure you run your code when the window has completely loaded.